# command to summarize a cluster of entries in a table

Tags: linux, text-processing, perl

I have a table that shows how many ASVs(columns) are clustered in one OTU(rows). Each ASV is represented by a value of 1.

```
#OTUID    ASV_1    ASV_2    ASV_3    ASV_4    ASV_5    ASV_6    ASV_7    ASV_8    ASV_9    ASV_10
OTU1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1
OTU2    0    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
OTU3    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1    1    0
```

I want to summarize the table to the following;

```
#OTUID    ASVs
OTU1    ASV_1, ASV_4, ASV_10
OTU2    ASV_2, ASV_5
OTU3    ASV_6, ASV_8, ASV_9
```

kindly help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following script assumes that you want to print the column **names** for all columns on each input line (after the first header line) which have the **value** `1`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my @titles=();

while(<>) {
  if ($. == 1) {
     @titles = split;         # get column titles
     print "#OTUID\tASVs\n";  # print the new output header
     next;
  };
  chomp;

  my @F=split;       # split the input line into fields, store in array @F

  my @ASVs=();       # @ASV array holds the titles for each matching field.

  foreach my $asv (1..$#F) {
    push @ASVs, $titles[$asv] if ($F[$asv] == 1);
  };

  print "$F[0]\t", join(",", @ASVs), "\n";
}
```

save it as, e.g., `alex.pl`, make it executable with `chmod +x alex.pl` and run it like so:

```
$ ./alex.pl input.txt 
#OTUID  ASVs
OTU1    ASV_1,ASV_4,ASV_10
OTU2    ASV_2,ASV_5
OTU3    ASV_6,ASV_8,ASV_9
```

Comment: Worked like magic. Thanks #cas

Answer (score 1):

```
$ perl -lane '$,="\t";
   $. == 1 and do{ $h{$_} = $F[$_] for 1..$#F; print $F[0], "ASVs"; next; };
   print $F[0], join ", ", map { $h{$_} } grep { $F[$_] == 1 } 1..$#F;
' file
```

**Results:**

```
#OTUID  ASVs
OTU1    ASV_1, ASV_4, ASV_10
OTU2    ASV_2, ASV_5
OTU3    ASV_6, ASV_8, ASV_9
```